# Check Box toggles rows to hide or show

Tags: google-apps-script, show-hide

Can I combine these scripts to work like a toggle to hide or show rows?

```
function onEdit(e){
if (e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value != "FALSE") return;
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.hideRows(23,4); // Hides rows
}

function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.showRows(23,4); // Shows rows
}
```

Comment: What is `e.Value == "TRUE"`  true represent ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e){
    //if e.vlaue  represent the current state of the records are shown/hide 
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1  ) return;
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
  if (  e.value != "FALSE"){
    sheet.showRows(23,4); // Shows rows
  }else{
    sheet.hideRows(23,4); // Hides rows
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Enter Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart > 1 ) {
    if(e.value == "TRUE") sh.showRows(23,4);
    if(e.value == "FALSE") sh.hideRows(23,4);
  }
}
```

You did not specify the checkbox row.

Comment: yes you are right, I would need to specify the location of the check box. I will have many check boxes, each when checked reveal's an additional section of information.

Comment: When I stack  them only the last one executes.

Comment: Every function in a project must have a unique name so I you mean that you are trying to employ multiple functions with the same name, that does not work.  You must separate  the functionality within the same function utilizing logic

Comment: so I can not create individual scripts for each section?      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
      //if (  e.value != "FALSE"){
      if ( A22= "FALSE"){
        sheet.showRows(23,20); // Shows rows
      }else{
        sheet.hideRows(23,20); // Hides rows
      }

}

Comment: If you wish to have separate scripts you may create unique installable onEdit triggers but the function should not be name onEdit() because that's reserved for the simple trigger.  You can give them each unique names but I would just create  individual sections in the onEdit(e) script.  In this case it was not necessary since they did the same thing.

Comment: "I would just create individual sections in the onEdit(e) script." so can I do that by setting a cell call out and a separate effective range? How would I do that?  the above example in my prior comment did not work.

Comment: All necessary information should be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) plus many example can be found on SO.